# Run batch file on startup NOT LOGON

Tags: network-shares, batch-file, windows-xp-embedded

I want to run a batch file that maps a network drive but all of the solutions I have found run the script in the start-up folder which isn't really what it says it is.

How do I map the drive BEFORE the user logs on?

Please don't mark this as a duplicate, I understand this has come up before but all of the solutions I can see on this site deal with the batch at logon.

Comment: Depending on how I interpret your question, there are several thing you could be getting at: Do you mean that you want access to a specific folder on your computer from another computer before someone log on? Like a network share? 

Or do you want to map a drive on the computer that hasn't been mapped already so that it's available for any user that logs in? Or something completely else that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have drives reconnect and remapped at startup by using the `net use` . . .`PERSISTENT`option.

For running batchfiles at startup, add your batchfile's name to:

**HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run**

Answer (score 0):

For this to work at computer startup, you'd have to give access to the Everyone/ANONYMOUS group via Share and NTFS permissions